# unable to post file+data using python-requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, usergrid, apigee-baas

I'm able to post file using curl

```
curl -X POST -i -F name='barca' -F country='spain' -F 
file=@/home/messi/Desktop/barca.png 'http://localhost:8080/new_org/hel/concerts'
```

Which I can get (file) as

```
 curl -X GET -H 'Accept: image/png' 'http://localhost:8080/new_org/hel/concerts/<id or name of entity>'
```

But when I tried same thing using `requests.post`, I got error. Does anybody know why this happen. (Post Error encounter when file pointer is not at last, but when file pointer is at last, I got response 200 but file is not posted)

```
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:8080/new_org/hel/concerts'
file = dict(file=open('/home/messi/Desktop/barca.png', 'rb'))
data = dict(name='barca', country='spain')
response = requests.post(url, files=file, data=data)
```

Error: (from [usergrid](https://github.com/apache/usergrid)) with response code: 400

```
{u'duration': 0,
 u'error': u'illegal_argument',
 u'error_description': u'value is null',
 u'exception': u'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException',
 u'timestamp': 1448330119021}
```

https://github.com/apache/usergrid

Comment: What's the error that you got?

Comment: Well I don't know, if your `curl` command can works fine, then the Python code maybe can also works.

Comment: Hmm...let me test your code...

Comment: There's no problem with your code...

Comment: Is this problem encounter due to different approach of sending file by curl and requests.post. using curl I only provide file path on my machine and using request, I provide open file. I case for testing purpose, url is  : https://api.usergrid.com/narayan0/sandbox/concerts

Comment: The POST requests from `curl` and `requests` are *basically* the same; you can compare the results by replacing your URL with `http://httpbin.org/post` and looking at the JSON response that server produces. The issue then must be with `usergrid`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't understand why post request from curl works and from requests doesn't. Do you have any idea why this type of issue might arise...

Comment: @Pattinson: a bug in the Java parser. What exactly is hard to say; there are subtle differences in the headers and how the multipart/form-data body is formed exactly (differences all well within the HTTP standard).

Comment: @Pattinson: perhaps ask the usergrid project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the problem is that Python is not sending a content-type field for the image that you are sending. I traced through the Usergrid code using a debugger and saw that curl *is* sending the the content-type for the image and Python is not.

I was able to get this exact code to work on my local Usergrid:

```
import requests
url = 'http://10.1.1.161:8080/test-organization/test-app/photos/'
files = { 'file': ('13.jpg', open('/Users/dave/Downloads/13.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}
data = dict(name='barca', country='spain')
response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
```

It is possible that Waken Meng's answer did not work because of the syntax of the files variable, but I'm no Python expert.

Answer (score 1):

I met a problem before when i try to upload image files. Then I read the [doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) and do this part:

> You can set the filename, content_type and headers explicitly:

Here is how I define the file_data:

```
file_data = [('pic', ('test.png', open('test.png'), 'image/png'))]
r = requests.post(url, files=file_data)
```

file_data should be a a list: [(param_name, (file_name, file, content_type))]

This works for me, hope can help you.

Comment: sorry ... as doc said, we can specify filename, content_type and headers explicitly but I don't need to do it... Do you think I need to specify for any reason? also this don't work... problem encounter as before, file not posted

Comment: Curl doesn't set a Content-Type header for the file field either.